# Is it possible to move JMenuBar without adding it in a JPanel

Tags: java, windows, swing, jpanel, jmenubar

I am facing a problem with my JMenuBar location in my Java application.

I am actually using ComponentResizer.java code from the [article](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/).

and everything with the resizing works fine except from the north area of my application
(undecorated JFrame) and its corners (of North Area) because the JMenuBar is preventing me from resizing from that area.

Is there a solution or maybe a hack to move the JMenuBar down a little or enable the Resizing 
in the north area?

I also use `setJMenuBar()` method to add the JMenuBar to the north area of my application.

Code:

```
  public class MyApp extends JFrame {

private MyApp frame;
private JMenuBar menuBar;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new MyApp();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public MyApp(){
    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents(){
    setTitle("MediaForm");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 673, 482);
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. No need to repeat `ComponentResizer`.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested this, but `JRootPane` is a `JComponet`, it may be possible to add a `EmptyBorder` to it, allowing the `JMenuBar` to be offset.

Failing that, you'll probably need to implement your own `JRootPane` to manage the layout of the `JMenuBar` & content pane

**UPDATE with Testing**

```
public class TestMenuFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestMenuFrame() throws HeadlessException {

        setTitle("Test");

        getRootPane().setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(new JMenu("Test"));

        setJMenuBar(mb);

        setSize(100, 100);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestMenuFrame().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: I don't think that this is my problem.I just have no access to JFrame listeners in the north area of my application

Comment: And I use an undecorated frame.Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Firstly, if you can add components to any part of the frame, you only need to walk the component hierarchy until you reach the JRootPane, besides which, you stated you used setJMenu, meaning you must have access to the frame. Secondary, I hardly think using an undecorated frame will make any difference to the solution I've suggested

Answer (score 1):

JMenuBar extends JComponent, therefore you can put it anywhere you would put an ordinary component. Note that it could be confusing to the users if you put it to unexpected locations.

Also see this: [add JMenuBar to a JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299846/add-jmenubar-to-a-jpanel)

Comment: How could I remove the JMenuBar from the JFrame to add a new Jpanel and then add the JMenuBar above it without losing its contents

Comment: I actually did it myself.Thanks for the help.It really helped me.